# How to prevent wcf from adding escape characters to response?

Tags: android, json, parsing, wcf

I use WCF as server and android app as client.
I have problem in parsing response in android if response contain escape characters, for example the user enters his name
`"mohammed  \\ main center // 77132131 "` the value in database.
The name of user in database as entered  contain backslash and for-slash.
WCF Create this response:

```
"[{\"name\":\" mohammed \/\/ main center \\\\\\\\ 77132131 \"}]"
```

I tried this in WCF server but the problem still in code

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

I tried replace all backslash in android but I did not getting the same value in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a string like you said it should look like this:

```
"[{\"name\":\"mohammed \\\\ main center // 77132131 \"}]"
```

I created a WCF service for testing, if you use the proxy class to call the service, you will get the following string:

```
[{"name":"mohammed \\ main center // 77132131 "}]
```

The following code is the implementation class of the server:

```
 public class Calculator : ICalculator
    {
        public string Test(string test)
        {
            return "[{\"name\":\"mohammed \\\\ main center // 77132131 \"}]";
        }
    }
```